# How to correctly terminate processes with named pipe. Unmatched usage of pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, named-pipes, terminate

I made bash script which calls two processes linked with named pipe, like this:

```
mkfifo pipe
gnuplot <pipe &
PIPE=pipe apl $*
rm pipe
wait $!
```

Here `apl` sends commands through `pipe` to `gnuplot`. When first finished second should finish too, then the script terminates.

(Note, question is not related neither `apl` nor `gnuplot`, you may imagine any other application instead.

The problem is that `apl` may, or may not open pipe (if it does not need to plot any graph). In case it not opening pipe gnuplot is waiting forever, and thus, script is not terminated.

If I try to terminate gnuplot with `echo 'exit' >pipe` it hangs in opposite case.

If I just remove `wait`, `gnuplot` will wait in background forever.

I cannot force `apl` to open and close a pipe (it controlled by operator which may forget doing it).

So how should both script and background process terminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I insert the following code before `rm pipe` it works for me:

```
exec 3>pipe
exec 3>&-
```

.

Explaination: The first `exec`-call creates a filedescriptor `3` directed to `pipe`. The second `exec`-call closes the filedescriptor `3`. In your case gnuplot will terminate because its `stdin` was closed - whether apl opened it beforehand or not.

Source: [How to avoid echo closing FIFO named pipes? - Funny behavior of Unix FIFOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410439/how-to-avoid-echo-closing-fifo-named-pipes-funny-behavior-of-unix-fifos/8436387#8436387)

Comment: I found that placing `exec 3>pipe` before `apl` and `exec 3>&-` after as in your link also works. Thanks.