# Mplayer and pipe streaming

Tags: bash, fifo, mplayer

I'd like to use mplayer to play a stream of files via a named pipe.

From [here](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/streaming.html) I read that *MPlayer can read from stdin (not named pipes)*.

named pipes can still be used in a bash script this way:

```
mkfifo pipe
cat pipe | mplayer -cache 1024 -cache-min 10 -really-quiet - &
cat test.wav > pipe
```

the problem with this is that after mplayer receives an EOF, it exits and I cannot pass more than one file, while I'd like mplayer to keep playing files through the pipe. The problem is somehow similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410439/how-to-avoid-echo-closing-fifo-named-pipes-funny-behavior-of-unix-fifos), from which the following script, meant to keep the pipe opened, is inspired:

```
mkfifo pipe
cat pipe | mplayer -cache 1024 -cache-min 10 -really-quiet - &
exec 3>pipe
cat test1.wav >&3
cat test2.wav >&3
..
exec 3>&- # close the pipe
```

the pipe remains indeed open; however, now despite the cache of mplayer getting filled, I get no playback unless I close the pipe, in which case it plays the first file only. I tried to send, after a file, an EOF signal:

```
mkfifo pipe
cat pipe | mplayer -cache 1024 -cache-min 10 -really-quiet - &
exec 3>pipe
cat test1.wav >&3
echo >&3
..
exec 3>&- # close the pipe
```

but still no luck.

Any suggestions on how to use mplayer as a stream player from a named pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/766414/how-to-prevent-terminating-command-to-send-eof-to-named-pipes)? In your case you should encapsulate all the `cat` commands:

```
mkfifo pipe
cat pipe | mplayer -cache 1024 -cache-min 10 -really-quiet - &
exec 3>pipe
(cat test1.wav test2.wav ) >&3
3>&- # close the pipe
```

In this way, when the command meets the closing parenthesis also send an EOF...

Honestly, I am not sure this is the answer, but it was too long for a comment... :)

In case this will work, the main downside is the memory usage...

Comment: Hi @RiccardoPetraglia, and  thanks - I'm afraid this would not yield the desired behavior, which is to play the data as I input them. But maybe this is just not what mplayer is meant to do :)