# MPlayer infinity loop with pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, fifo, mplayer, mkfifo

I'd like to use mplayer to play a video in an infinity loop with no interrupts between. So I tryied it with a mkfifo pipe. Like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40637808/mplayer-and-pipe-streaming).

```
mkfifo pipe
(cat pipe | mplayer -cache 10000 -cache-min 0 -really-quiet - ) &
cat video.avi >> pipe       
until [ -e /tmp/stop_loop ]   #stop file
do 
  sleep 20                    #video.avi is 25sec long
  cat video.avi >> pipe     #fill pipe with the video again slightly before the first video ends
done
```

Anyone an idea why this don't work?
Somehow the pipe can be filled only one time.
Or is it because of the video format .avi? But I tried it with .mp4 whith still no luck too.

Comment: *Or is it because of the video format .avi?* Most probably

Comment: Why is it going to mypipe and not pipe?

Comment: @oguzismail which video format you think would be a better one?

Comment: @bobdylan yes it shold be pipe instead of mypipe

Comment: I wonder if instead of `cat` you could do something like: `mplayer -dumpstream -dumpfile pipe`

Comment: @YANNlK - see my answer for your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while true
do
(cat pipe | mplayer -cache 10000 -cache-min 0 -really-quiet - ) &
cat video.avi >> pipe
sleep 25
done
```

This works (where the video is 25 seconds long) though probably needs more thought (e.g. get video length, not sure about the cache options etc.)

edit: this seems better:

```
mplayer -fs -loop 0 video.avi -really-quiet
```

which is just loop a file forever. I'm not sure of the need to pipe etc. to be honest.

edit2: I missed the part where you wanted a smooth stream. Putting the loop AFTER the filename fixes this:

```
mplayer -fs video.avi -loop 0 -really-quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better idea would be to use mplayer's `slave` mode; this would let you control it while leaving it free to cache/seek and do whatever it wants with a real video file.

`slave` mode is a simple text protocol, with queries and replies on standard input. It is described here http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/control.html and here http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt

but you can search the internet for more info and examples.