# read then write to c programme from shell script

Tags: c, linux, shell, deadlock, named-pipes

I have a short c programme that outputs 3 lines then reads from stdin, and I would like to use a shell script to interact with it as follows:

1. read c output, line by line `while read line; do ...; done <$out_`
2. save 2nd line `if [ "$count" == 2 ]; then input=$line; fi`
3. send saved line back to programme `echo $input >$in_`

I'm using named pipes in the shell script to redirect the output and input of the c programme:

```
./iotest >$out_ <$in_ &
```

but I'm not getting the results I'd expect.

### Problem

After creating the pipes `out_` and `in_` with `mkfifo`, I have a `while read` loop but it seems to lead to a deadlock.  Nothing is read, and the shell script gets stuck on the read command.

I tried adding `cat >$in_ &` before launching `iotest`, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410439/how-to-avoid-echo-closing-fifo-named-pipes-funny-behavior-of-unix-fifos/8436387#8436387), to open `in_`for writing without actually writing anything. This unblocks the read but doesn't let me input to `in_` (my c programme acts as if I'd written \x00 to stdin, and the `echo $input >$in_` command hangs).

### What I've tried

I've read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs#53646) that read blocks if there is no writer, and wihtout `cat >$in_ &` I have `iotest` writing to `out_`, and `read` reading from it, I'm trying to redirect `in_` to `iotest`without writing anything to it from the start.

But why adding the cat command makes the c programme fail at reading, I don't know. The same happens if I exchange `cat >$in_ &` with `while true; do :; done >$in_&` or `exec 3>$in_ &` (`exec 3>$in_`, as proposed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366219/prevent-automatic-eofs-to-a-named-pipe-and-send-an-eof-when-i-want-it), also hangs).

### Code

This is my c code:

```
$ cat iotest.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char A[9] = "";
    printf("hello. please send me the following line:\n");
    printf("input me\n");
    printf("now send me the line:\n");
    int ret = read(0,A,8);
    fprintf(stderr,"read returned %i\n",ret);
    if(ret != -1) {
        printf("You sent: %s\n", A);
        if (strcmp(A,"input me") == 0) {
            printf("correct!\n");
        } else {
            printf("wrong line.\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("read failed.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the shell script I've tested:

```
$ cat runiotest.sh 
#!/bin/bash

in_=/tmp/testpipein
out_=/tmp/testpipeout

mkfifo $in_
mkfifo $out_
count=0
input=""

./iotest >$out_ <$in_ &
while read line
do
    count=$((count+1))
    echo "line number $count:"
    echo $line
    if [ "$count" == 2 ]
    then
        input=$line
    fi
    if [ "$count" == 3 ]
    then
        echo "$input" >$in_
    fi
done < $out_

rm -f $in_
rm -f $out_
```

I've tested this on 32-bit debian and 64-bit ubuntu, compiling with gcc, and executing the shell script with bash.

### Results

without the added cat command:

```
$ /bin/bash/ ./runiotest.sh
(hangs)
```

with added `cat >$in_ &`:

```
$ /bin/bash ./runiotest.sh
read returned 0
line number 1:
hello. please send me the following line:
line number 2:
input me
line number 3:
now send me the line:
line number 4:
You sent:
line number 5:
wrong line.
```

### Summary

So my question is: What is wrong with my shell script, and how can I modify it to read then write to my c programme? I can't change the c code itself but can fiddle with the shell script.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you can, try running the script under `strace -f` (see the man page for output options etc.). It's really helpful to see which process is blocking on what file descriptor.

Comment: Opening a fifo for writing blocks until something else opens it for reading, and vis versa.

Comment: You "C" program expects input (from the pipe). Your script has to send the input to the program (or another process should provided it)

Comment: Thanks @Useless. I'll have a look at strace!

Comment: @dash-o, surely I should be able to read the output of the c programme before writing to its input? That's how it works when stdout and stdin are used: the output is printed normally and the programme stops at the stdin read.

Comment: Is the `cat` getting terminated?  It seems that you ought to just explicitly add that to the script.  It feels like you are running `cat` in a way that causes it to immediately terminate, so that `read` immediately returns zero.

Comment: For example, if you are literally adding the line `cat > $in_ &` in the script, but executing the script with `runiotest.sh <&-`, then `cat will immediately terminate and the read in iotest will return 0.  (s/will/may/, since there are a lot of race conditions here that will depend on the order in which processes execute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was **the buffering of the c programme output**. Removing the buffering with `stdbuf` solved it:

```
cat >$in_ &
stdbuf -o0 ./iotest <$out_ >$in_ &
```

With this change, the output is as it should:

```
$ /bin/bash ./runiotest.sh 
line number 1
hello. please send me the following line:
line number 2
input me
line number 3
now send me the line:
read returned 8
line number 4
You sent: input me
line number 5
correct!
```

Just to add, using stdbuf doesn't work if the executable has the setuid bit set. In this case, you can use `unbuffer` from the expect utility.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
./iotest >$out_ <$in_ &
while read line; do ...; done < $out_
```

Here, the subshell attemts to open $out_ for writing and $in_ for reading, and it will not even execute `iotest` until both of those fifos are open.  Without your added `cat`, the subshell is unable to open `$in_` until there is some writer, so `iotest` never even begins to execute.  When you add the `cat`, the subshell is able to open `$in_`, and the main shell acts as a reader for `$out_`, so the subshell is able to open both fifos and execute `iotest`.  As to the behavior you are seeing, it is a bug in your iotest.c.  Print the value returned by `read` (to stderr!), include a declaration of `read`, and try using `!= -1` instead of `> -1`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's true that I should be checking for `read(...) =! -1` as this is the value returned on error. In my case, the read function returns 0 for EOF, and including `unistd.h` for the read declaration doesn't change the behaviour I've described in my question. I'll update the code with your corrections, though.